# spring 3 annotation dependency injection

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations

For a new legacy application I have to use Latest Spring framework 3.x with Hibernate 3.x.  Earlier I used Spring IoC with xml configuration. Now i would like to go for annotation based IoC.

Below link from rose india shows use annotation without xml file.
[rose india](http://www.roseindia.net/spring/spring3/configuration-spring.shtml)

but i have found some other way of implementing in another site:
[blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/seemarich/archive/2007/11/annotation_base.html)

I am confused here which way to implement IoC with latest technology.
Please refer some good site for sample. Also please share some sample code for IoC with annotation.

> EDIT:
>
> Spring reference document 3.x says use **@Configuration** or xml configuration i.e. with annotation **<context:annotation-config/>**. Which one is better to use? Why?

Comment: Ignore rose india's stuff.  It's absolutely terrible.

Comment: I maintain an operational example here: http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/08/spring-ioc-container-with-annotations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to start with the [Spring 3.0 Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).  If you already are familiar with Dependency Injection using xml configuration, take a look at Spring's annotation support in [`Section 3.9 Annotation-based container configuration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config).  There should be plenty of details there to help get you started.

If this is not a WebApp, and you need to load the `ApplicationContext` yourself, you should take a look at [`Section 3.11 Java-based container configuration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java).  This section details how you can create your `ApplicationContext` with your xml configuration.

I would recommend using the `@Autowired` annotations for wiring with `@Component` annotation for defining beans within the `ApplicationContext`, and use the `scan(String)` method provided by the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` to find all annotated components:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
  ctx.scan("your.package.here");
  ctx.refresh();
  MyService myService = ctx.getBean(MyService.class);
  //use myService
}
```

Comment: do i need to use new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(); to load xml file? only bean declaration is sufficient in xml file?

Comment: ok, in my context xml file do i need to specify bean id and its property for IoC?

Comment: You can just add: <context:annotation-config  /> to your context.xml file to have it load the annotations. Then use: <context:component-scan base-package="my.package" /> to import all the annotated classes. This requires no code whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple and clear one:

http://www.simplespringtutorial.com/annotations.html

Comment: @gupta59 Thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going with adding: `<context:annotation-config />` to your xml context file to have it load the annotations. Then use: `<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />` to import all the annotated classes. This requires no code whatsoever and is incredibly clean. You can also add include/exclude filters to the scan in the xml file.

Then, just use whatever annotations you want in your classes. Make sure of the annotation construction to give them IDs for referencing later, i.e. @Component("mycomponentbean").

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I have recorded a video tutorial for this topic, which is available (for free) here: https://www.udemy.com/spring-framework-video-tutorial